# Python dictionary key value swapped?

Tags: python

I'm learning how to use a dictionary in python. However, it seems like when I print my dictionary, some items in my dictionary are swapped. Eg. [key,value],[value,key],[value,key],[key,value].

Is there something I'm missing?

```
def create_neighbourhood():
    maingrid = []
    coord_grid = {}
    grid = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
    for i in range(0,len(grid)):
        for j in range(0,10):
            current_cell = grid[i]+ str(j+1)
            current_coords = str(i) +","+str(j)
            coord_grid = {current_cell,current_coords}
            maingrid.append(coord_grid)
    return maingrid
```

Comment: You're appending a `set()` to a `list` and `set`s are unordered

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but for both style and correctness, loop on containers directly (`for item in grid`) or use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) when you want indices (`for i, item in enumerate(grid)`)

Comment: in coord_grid use : instead of ,

Comment: I see. I'll take a look at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why

You are using sets instead of dictionaries.  You must divide the two items by a `:` not a `,` .  Sets don't enforce order so the elements will be periodically swapped with this implementation.

### New Code

```
def create_neighbourhood():
    maingrid = []
    coord_grid = {}
    grid = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
    for i in range(0,len(grid)):
        for j in range(0,10):
            current_cell = grid[i]+ str(j+1)
            current_coords = str(i) +","+str(j)
            coord_grid = {current_cell:current_coords}
            maingrid.append(coord_grid)
    return maingrid

print(create_neighbourhood())
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I was wondering what I missed. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll make this the answer in abit